# Control beaglebone black (linux) with android smartphone through usb cable

Tags: android, linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have a beaglebone-black/raspberry-pi that is running a basic command line linux system. I am currently operating the board with a keyboard (usb) an an lcd screen (hdmi). Now I want to control the board with my android smartphone through a usb cable instead of keyboard and screen.

Example. There is an application on my android phone say Linux Terminal. That application sends command strings to the terminal running on board, receives the output and displays it.

I can develop android applications and I am also very fluent with C and linux but I am not very good with interfaces (usb) and drivers etc. I have never used a driver in programming.

I wanted to ask is it even possible. If so, is there any existing tool that can do this. If no such tool exists , then give me a **brief** outline of the whole process (which drivers to use etc).

Comment: It is definitely possible. The easiest way with USB is to go for virtual COM ports. Google "usb-serial android" for examples. You can then establish communication with any PC using any serial terminal application on PC side, if that works fine go for your custom application on beaglebone/raspberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

- Termius
- JuiceSSH or
- Connectbot

There is also a documentation for Termius:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/android.md

Best regards,
Ben

Comment: that was exactly what i needed. Thank a lot